# Getting same result based on different input

Tags: mysql, database

Let me repost my question. I think my previous question might confuse people.
Sorry for the confusion.

I have a table called vuln_info and I am trying to query based on vuln_name.

If I query like this

```
SELECT vuln_id FROM vuln_info where vuln_name="Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate"
```

I have row like

```
vuln_id vuln_name 

 100    Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate
```

It returns vuln_id(100) because the vuln_name exactly match with input

However, input can be changeable. It can be like

"Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate present" or "machine Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate"  which contains  Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate

What is the way to write query to get vuln_id(100) even though input has extra String.

Please check this link

[sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc2c/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc2c/1)

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to match to random words in a string, then look at MySQL's full text index.  I think it can do what you want.

Comment: I think that is what the `like` operator is for

Comment: All inputs contain "Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate". is there any match or contain function in mysql?

Comment: I tried to put where vuln_name like "%$input%" it returns nothing if input has extra words.

Comment: `where vuln_name Like "%Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate%"` should do it

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc2c/1

Comment: If input has extra words, this  Like approach won't work. This will only work if you have multiple values that contain the same substring in different records.

Comment: what is the solution for that?

Comment: @draford. i updated my answer with an answer. see if it works for you

Comment: @draford. Were you able to accomplish what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to search it with a behavior similar to a like but in reverse, you can try and reverse it also:

```
SELECT vuln_id 
FROM vuln_info 
WHERE "present Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate" like CONCAT('%', vuln_name, '%');
```

You can change the text at the left of your LIKE with your input.

See it working in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc2c/4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT vuln_id 
FROM   vuln_info 
WHERE  vuln_name like "%Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate%"
```

Answer (score 0):

For string search we use `like` operator

```
SELECT vuln_id  FROM vuln_info 
WHERE vuln_name LIKE '%Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate%';
```

you have to use % op  as per your requirements.